# How to efficiently write the result of thousands of RPC calls to Rust SQLite DB

Tags: database, sqlite, rust, parallel-processing, rust-tokio

I have to make over 100K RPC calls are while setting up my Rust server. This is a one time operation when the server initializes. I have to write the result of these 100K+ fetches to a DB. I'm using rusqlite for my DB. And making RPC calls with reqwest. I want this to be an async operation as the server should be able to handle queries by reading from the DB while the initialization process is still under process which may take a few hours as it's making 100K RPC calls.

I tried to spawn a tokio async task & make the RPC calls inside it:

```
let handle = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
    let conn = Connection::open("rpc_results.db")?;
    for _ in 0..200000 {
        let res = fetch_rpc_endpoint().await?;
        write_to_db(res, conn)?;
    }
});
```

Here I'm writing to DB after every RPC call which is highly inefficient. I can optimize this by saving 100 RPC results in a Vec & batch writing to the DB.

Is it possible to further optimize this? I'm thinking of parallelizing the RPC calls & batch writing to the DB parallely, is this possible keeping in mind the race conditions for the DB. This might be a concern as I have to open a new connection to simultaneously read from the partially written DB.

Or any Rust library combinations to achieve this as this seems to be a standard problem?

Comment: The first thing to do is  to re-use the same connection. If you want to use the already-received data in the application, you can't avoid having to write after each call, but you can do it in batches (for example, write to DB every 5 minutes).

Comment: If you search SO there are posts about optimising insertion speed with sqlite, those would generally be applicable. Generally speaking both working in a transaction and batching inserts will be applicable. An other option to evaluate might be to buffer the insertions and use something like CSV import but I don't remember if sqlite can do that via normal APIs.

Comment: I mean [something like that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5fe1dc21321c3952920bb617af0ba140).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Don't you think this could be done a lot less noisily with `buffer_unordered` and `chunks`? [docs](https://docs.rs/futures-util/latest/futures_util/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffered)

Comment: @Caesar `buffer_unordered()` does not do the same thing, it does not spawn all at the same time. Of course, it may actually be desired :)

Comment: Hm. A short explanation on when that may or may not be desired might be in order... It's a performance difference, right? If you use a multi-threaded rt, spawning each `fetch_rpc_endpoint` might put those onto different threads, whereas my code below polls all the futures from a single thread, right?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the comments, this can be achieved relatively neatly with `futures::{Try,}StreamExt`'s `buffer_unordered` and `try_chunks`:

```rust
futures::stream::iter(0..100)
    .map(|_| fetch_rpc_endpoint())
    .buffer_unordered(5) // RPC parallelism
    .try_chunks(20) // DB insert chunk size
    .map(|data| {
        write_to_db(data.map_err(|TryChunksError(_, e)| e)?, &mut conn)?;
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(())
    })
    .try_collect::<()>()
    .await?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d20477feb813ac72fa4605393fd07d94)

Notes:

- If you care about order, there's also `buffered` instead of `buffer_unordered`.
- You might want to wrap your `write_to_db` in a `spawn_blocking`.
- Your `tokio::spawn` on the outer loop does not achieve any parallelism/concurrency.